# Having difficulty using R programming to implement a trading strategy using multiple securities

Tags: r, summary, portfolio, trading

I am currently attempting to implement a trading idea that I have been playing around with. It consists of 50+ securities and has a strategy very similar to this one. (Current package I am using is quantmod).

http://www.r-bloggers.com/backtesting-a-simple-stock-trading-strategy/

For those who aren't interested in clicking, it is a strategy that will look at the pass X days( in his case 200 ) and enter a position depending on the peak reached in the stock.  I understand how to do this strategy for my idea, but I cannot grasp how to aggregate my data into one summary.

Is there a way I can consolidate the summary for all the positions I have entered into one larger portfolio summary and chart that against the S&P 500?

Any advice on where I can find resources or being lead to the information. I have looked at portfolio analysis package for R and I do not believe that will be much help to me.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: In the link, at the bottom, there are 3 indexes that are FTSE, N225, DJIA. Could i combine those 3 summaries to show the same output as below, BUT combined

```
FTSE:
Me Index 
Cumulative Return           3.56248582     3.8404476
Annual Return               0.05667121     0.0589431
Annualized Sharpe Ratio     0.45907768     0.3298633
Win %                       0.53216374     0.5239884
Annualized Volatility       0.12344579     0.1786895
Maximum Drawdown           -0.39653398    -0.5256991
Max Length Drawdown         1633.00000     2960.0000
```

Could I get that same output but for the 3 securities data combined? Is there a effective way of doing that. Thank you so much. Happy holidays

Comment: Are you looking for where to get the data for the positions? Or you know where the data is and you need help figuring out how to pull it into R?

Comment: It would help us understand what you want if you provide some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my original post. If you guys have any advice or source I can learn, I would greatly appreciate it.

@shoover I understand how to pull the data. I just do not understand how to put all the summary data into an aggregate form to have a similar output to the above. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear to me what you mean by "combine" in this case. If you want a single column representing the combined returns from all three exchanges as if they were a single unified market, that's really tricky, because the exchanges trade in different currencies (British pounds; U.S. dollars, Japanese Yen, etc.). The underlying analysis would have to be modified substantially to take into account fluctuating daily foreign exchange rates.

I suspect that this is NOT want you want. Rather, you are simply asking how to take three sequential two-column outputs and turn them into a single parallel six-column output.

If that is indeed what you want, then you need to rewrite the `testStrategy()` function shown near the bottom of the link.  As it's currently written, that function takes three inputs: an index name `myStock` (with allowed values of FTSE, DJIA, or N225), and two integer values, `nHold` and `nHigh`.  You would need to change it so that it instead accepts five inputs; e.g., `myStockA`, `myStockB` and `myStockC`, plus the two integer values already mentioned.  Then each of the lines currently referring to `myStock` would have to be replicated three times.  Finally, the two `cbind()` lines that you see at the bottom would have to be modified so that instead of merging the data together into only two columns, you include all six.

For a good intro tutorial on how to write and modify your own R functions, please see [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions). To understand how to use the `cbind()` function, which you will have to call with six rather than two inputs, please see [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html).